# Len not working when there are spaces in data

Tags: sql-server

Using the code below is not working as there are spaces in Column 2. e.g. 026923102690542625548030 (1)
The spaces are needed in between the number and (1) but I believe there is also training spaces which can be stripped out.

```
   select RIGHT([Column 2], len([Column 2]) - 19) AS newcol2, [Column 2] from [dbo].[231]
```

This is returning nothing in newcol2 when I am trying to show 48030 (1)

I've tried replacing len with DATALENGTH and that just gives me a duplicate of [Column 2]

*** added with more information

When I try

```
    select 
RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],' ','')) - 2) AS newcol2, 
[Column 2] from [dbo].[231]
```

I get the result

```
newcol2      [Column 2]
(1)          026923102690970425568331 (1)                     
             026923102690970525568331
```

I need the newcol2 column to say 68331 (1) and 68331 
The field types are nvarchar(50)

---

Tried the following

```
    select 
RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],CHAR(10),'')) - 19) AS newcol2, 
[Column 2] from [dbo].[231]

    select 
RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],CHAR(13),'')) - 19) AS newcol2, 
[Column 2] from [dbo].[231]
```

still the same

*** Added with solution

```
    WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Column 2] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 2],CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')))
        FROM [dbo].[231]
)
SELECT
     RIGHT([Column 2], len([Column 2]) - 19) AS newcol2,
    [Column 2]
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: It works perfectly on my MS. Could you provide table definition?

Comment: They are all nvarchar(50) fields. when i copy and paste the column 2 field I get lots of spaces at the end. but they don't seem to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try length after replacing the space

```
select 
RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],' ','')) - 19) AS newcol2, 
[Column 2] from [dbo].[231]
```

OR

```
select 
    RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],' (1)','(1)')) - 19) AS newcol2, 
    [Column 2] from [dbo].[231]
```

I'm getting the right answer when I ran this

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(50)='026923102690542625548030 (1)'

SELECT
    RIGHT(@T, LEN(@T) - 19) AS newcol2,
    @T
```

Try Replacing CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) from the column and calculate len. that might work. like this

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Column 2] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 2],CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'')))
        FROM [dbo].[231]
)
SELECT
    RIGHT([Column 2], len(REPLACE([Column 2],' ','')) - 19) AS newcol2, 
    [Column 2]
    FROM CTE
```

Comment: Tried both, and there is nothing in newcol2

Comment: Can you provide some more sample data ?

Comment: Yes i get the right answer with the bottom one, there must be trailing characters in the data itself

Comment: startcopy-026923102690000425511040                         stopcopy

Comment: Can you give me an example on replcing the CHAR(10) and CHAR(13) please ?

Comment: @Emma I've added it to the answer

Comment: Yes, that works... apart from those with the space and (1) at the end are missing the first digit.

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if you got the expected result. So in future, it will be useful for others.